# Помогите решить задачу на JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Я изучаю js и столкнулся с задачей, которая никак не укладывается в голове. Помогите понять, что я делаю не так? Заранее благодарю)

Условие:

Создать функцию которая принимает массив пользователей, поле на которое хочу проверить и значение на которое хочу проверять. Проверять что все аргументы переданы. Возвращать новый массив с пользователями соответствующие указанным параметрам.

**Мой код:**

```js
users = [
  {name: 'Pavel', gender: 'male', age: 29},
  {name: 'Anna', gender: 'female', age: 18},
  {name: 'Fiona', gender: 'female', age: 19},
  {name: 'Julia', gender: 'female', age: 28},
  {name: 'Alex', gender: 'male', age: 23},
  {name: 'Sonya', gender: 'female', age: 17},
  {name: 'Frank', gender: 'male', age: 44},
  {name: 'John', gender: 'male', age: 49},
  {name: 'Greta', gender: 'female', age: 57},
];

function funcGetUsers(arrayUsers, key, keyValue) {
  let endArray = arrayUsers.slice();

  for (let user in endArray) {
    if (endArray[user][key] != keyValue) {
      endArray.splice(user, 1);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  
  return endArray;
}

let newUser = funcGetUsers(users, 'gender', 'female');
console.log(newUser);
```

Comment: а откуда известно что что-то не так?

Comment: 4: {name: "John", gender: "male", age: 49}

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать так попроще

```js
function funcGetUsers(arrayUsers, key, keyValue) {
    return arrayUsers.filter(item => item[key] === keyValue);
}

let users = [
{name: 'Pavel', gender: 'male', age: 29},
{name: 'Anna', gender: 'female', age: 18},
{name: 'Fiona', gender: 'female', age: 19},
{name: 'Julia', gender: 'female', age: 28},
{name: 'Alex', gender: 'male', age: 23},
{name: 'Sonya', gender: 'female', age: 17},
{name: 'Frank', gender: 'male', age: 44},
{name: 'John', gender: 'male', age: 49},
{name: 'Greta', gender: 'female', age: 57}
];

let newUser = funcGetUsers(users, 'gender', 'female');
console.log(newUser);
```

PS. А ваша проблема вы мутируете массив при этом перебираете его, что не приветствуется.

```js
const users = [
    {name: 'Pavel', gender: 'male', age: 29},
    {name: 'Anna', gender: 'female', age: 18},
    {name: 'Fiona', gender: 'female', age: 19},
    {name: 'Julia', gender: 'female', age: 28},
    {name: 'Alex', gender: 'male', age: 23},
    {name: 'Sonya', gender: 'female', age: 17},
    {name: 'Frank', gender: 'male', age: 44},
    {name: 'John', gender: 'male', age: 49},
    {name: 'Greta', gender: 'female', age: 57}
];

function funcGetUsers(arrayUsers, key, keyValue){
    let result = [];
    for (let user of arrayUsers) {
        if (user[key] === keyValue) {
            result.push(user);
        }
    }
    return result;
};

const newUser = funcGetUsers(users, 'gender', 'female');
console.log(newUser);
```

Comment: @Pr13rak я имел ввиду второй вариантю он не короткий

Answer (score 2):

Выше указали самый быстрый и простой способ, предложу еще свой, который ближе к вашему. Различие заключается в том, что здесь не создается копия массива и потом из нее не вырезаются значения, а наоборот - в пустой итоговый массив добавляются только подходящие:

```js
const users = [
    {name: 'Pavel', gender: 'male', age: 29},
    {name: 'Anna', gender: 'female', age: 18},
    {name: 'Fiona', gender: 'female', age: 19},
    {name: 'Julia', gender: 'female', age: 28},
    {name: 'Alex', gender: 'male', age: 23},
    {name: 'Sonya', gender: 'female', age: 17},
    {name: 'Frank', gender: 'male', age: 44},
    {name: 'John', gender: 'male', age: 49},
    {name: 'Greta', gender: 'female', age: 57}
];

const funcGetUsers = (arrayUsers, key, keyValue) => {
    let endArray = [];
    for (let user in arrayUsers) {
        if (arrayUsers[user][key] === keyValue) {
            endArray.push(arrayUsers[user]);
        }
    }
    return endArray;
};

const newUser = funcGetUsers(users, 'gender', 'female');
console.log(newUser);
```

Comment: А возможно ли реализовать это не используя стрелочные функции, зная только самые базовые, просто это урок определённого этапа, где я знаю только простые функции и базовые методы массивов, slice, splice, shift, pop?

Comment: да возможно это

Comment: А не подскажите как?

Comment: обновил ответ посмотрите выше